# PHP Scandir Not Automatically in Alphabetical Order?

Tags: php, sorting, scandir

TIA.  With my remedial PHP skills, I can't figure out why scandir isn't automatically sorting alphabetically.  (It would also be nice to have folders grouped together and sorted alphabetically and files grouped together and sorted alphabetically, but that isn't critical.)  What am I missing?

```
<?php
$dir = './customers/' . $customer . "/";
$exclude = array(".","..",".htaccess");
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach($files as $key=>$dir){
            if(!in_array($dir, $exclude)){
    echo ("<a href=\"./customers/$customer/".$dir."\">".$dir."</a><br>");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: REVISED: The directory alphabetizes correctly when the first letter of _all_ file names are lower-case (or, I assume, when the first letter of _all_ file names are upper-case). Is there a way to keep them alphabetized so that the first letter of the file names can be case-insensitive?

Comment: RESOLVED by using natcasesort:

<?php
$dir = './customers/' . $customer . "/";
$exclude = array(".","..",".htaccess");
 if (is_dir($dir)) {
  $files = scandir($dir);
  natcasesort($files);
     foreach($files as $key=>$dir){
         if(!in_array($dir, $exclude)){
             echo ("<a href=\"./customers/$customer/".$dir."\">".$dir."</a><br>");
        }
    }
}
?>
Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: If you have an answer, you should post it as an answer (not a comment) and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 7):

As WGD said, you must use [natcasesort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) by the following way:

```
$files = scandir($dir);
natcasesort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // your code
}
```